# How to split a string at boundaries between character groups

Tags: python, regex

My question is how to group/split a Python string into continuous sequences of same-type characters.

I have a string like

```py
s = "https:var///rer/tr.ewr,uuu234 34,5\n"
```

And I need to split it like

```py
[
'https' 
':' 
'var' 
'///' 
'rer' 
'/' 
'tr' 
'.' 
'ewr' 
',' 
'uuu' 
'234' 
'34' 
',' 
'5\n'
]
```

So the logic is to group characters by some their types: digits, text, punctuation.

Is there some easy way to do it in Python?

Comment: Shouldn't there be a `' '` entry after `'234'`, and `'5'` be separated from `'\n'`?

Answer (score 1):

Wow, it's pretty easy actually:

```
[m for m in re.split(r'([a-z]+|[0-9]+)', s) if m.strip()]
```